# how to build a postman like web interface?

Tags: node.js, api, express, postman

I am new to node.js and I have been learning it since a week. I want to build a postman like web interface in node.js and express which calls an api and performs get , put , post operations same as postman.

I want to know that how can I call an api from my node.js and express script and perform the above operations?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) library for doing http requests, it should help you get rid of boilerplate code. Usual choice for web server (that will serve your user interface) is [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express). Probably best is to write SPA app in static html and call JSON-based api made on express. You can use some templates like [Twig](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twig) if you choose to do dynamically generated html.

I understand, the main motivation behind making it node.js app is to overcome browser request restrictions (ie. same-origin policy). Other than that it sounds like there's little you can't to with browser side scripts (Postman likely benefits here from being ran as browser plug-in to skip restrictions).